# Adding Custom UIButton To subView

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, subview

I have subview which it initiated by touch on the UIbutton in the main view.
Once the subview pops up it displays a label with the info I provided. This all works. I just need an UIbutton to show up so I can then set it up to dismiss the subview and go back to the main view.  i have searched all over and have found nothing that helps.

Here is what my code in my .m file looks like:

```
////Button that Displays Subview with Its Label and Button
- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender
/////UI Subview

{UIView *mySubview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,320, 480)];

[self.view addSubview:mySubview];
mySubview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
mySubview.alpha = .7f;

//////Label in SubView

{UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 50)];
label.text = @"Here is info";
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];

[self.view addSubview:label];


////Button in Subview

//create the button
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button-info-x.png"]     forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//set the position of the button
button.frame = CGRectMake(120, 252, 68, 68);


//add the button to the view
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Now I just need to add an action to the UIButton to dismiss the Subview?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First Take IBOutlet of subView and add it to the main View.

```
 IBOutlet UIView *subView;
```

Then, add UIButton to the SubView like this:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

//set the position of the button
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30);

//set the button's title
[button setTitle:@"Click Me!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[btnMenu addTarget:self action:@selector(your MethodName:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

//add the button to the view
[subView addSubview:button];
```

Then,

```
-(IBAction)your MethodName:(id)sender {


}
```

In Above Method Remove SubView from Main View.

Comment: I edited my code and put it above  in my post. please look at that and then tell me how to make an action for the button. I'm  slightly lost

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply looking to set an image for a UIButton instead of a title, you're looking for the `- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state`method.

You should check the [UIButton reference](http://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDYQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html&ei=uRZoT5HmK4XmrAeP5rnzBw&usg=AFQjCNH0zcmZNW1jVkFgZJR-3D8iIeYDTg) for more info.

Comment: Thanks I created the UIButton and have the image for it. Now I just need the UIbutton to dismiss the subview. Any help with that?

Comment: //create the button
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button-info-x.png"]       forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //set the position of the button
    button.frame = CGRectMake(120, 252, 68, 68);
    //add the button to the view
    [self.view addSubview:button];

Comment: Use - (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents to assign which method you need the button to fire when clicked. Now, in that method, I guess you can dismiss the subview.

Answer (score 0):

Add Target to the custom button

```
{

.....

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(your dismiss:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

.......

}
-(IBAction)your dismiss:(id)sender 
{

   // write the dismissal code here

}
```